# Entering "vi mode" in gnome-terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, vim

I use `ssh -X user@IP` to connect to an Ubuntu Server which has had `gnome-terminal` installed on it.

When inside `gnome-terminal`, occasionally I accidentally hit a key combination and the terminal behaves differently. I *think* I have entered "vi mode". As an example, after I have hit this mysterious combination, I can press <kbd>-</kbd> and the font size of the terminal gets smaller.

I have to press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to get back into the normal mode.

Can anyone tell me what key combination I may have hit, and provide links or useful hints for the things I might be able to do with "vi mode"?

I have tried searching Google but haven't found anything particularly good - most pages refer to "vi mode" inside vi.

For information, I am using a French AZERTY keyboard, and the key combination I think I hit is <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> (on AZERTY keyboards the number keys provide punctuation unless <kbd>Shift</kbd> is pressed - the key I am pressing has the 6 on it), so that I can get the `|` character.

Comment: "vi mode" is not mode of the terminal window itself, but the shell which is running inside it. I think it's not the case though, it's maybe you've activated somehow the 'font size' option of the terminal itself, maybe because of your other keyboard layout, but I am only guessing now. I can't check it out since the kbd combo you've mentioned is used by another purpose in my config.

Comment: In my gnome-terminal, I hit `Crtl` and `-` to make fonts smaller, and `Ctrl-Shift` and `+` to make them larger.  I wonder if you've gotten the keymap so that it is emulating Ctrl with a different key combo?   `loadkeys defkeymap` worked on some older systems, but I can't get it to find a default keymap on my system.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Usually `vi` mode is set in bash with `set -o vi` .
By default, and contrary to the editor itself, you will be in `insert` mode.
You can hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> and <kbd>i</kbd> to move between insert and command mode.

> When you enter a line in vi mode, you
>   are already placed in `insertion'
>   mode, as if you had typed an "i".
>   Pressing ESC switches you into
>   "command" mode, where you can edit the
>   text of the line with the standard vi
>   movement keys, move to previous
>   history lines with "k" and subsequent
>   lines with "j" and so forth.

<sup>(from [linuxselfhelp](http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/gnu/bash/html_chapter/bashref_8.html) )</sup>

To go to the default mode, use `set -o emacs` .

According to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5465/vi-mode-in-freetalk) , you can toggle out of emacs mode (and back) with Meta+Ctrl+J .  But I can't get that to work on my keyboard (perhaps because I'm not sure what Meta is mapped to).

Here's a link with some editing commands : [hyperex.org : vi mode](http://www.hypexr.org/bash_tutorial.php#vi) .

Here's another link to a cheat-sheet type reference : [catonmat.net](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-vi-editing-mode-cheat-sheet) .